Categorical proof of Kolmogorov extension theorem in stochastic process
I'm recently working on searching some applications of category theory on stochastic process and found this on Mathoverflow. The user Tom LaGatta states that one can prove Kolmogorov extension theorem (The author said Kolmogorov-Centsov theorem but I think he meant Kolmogrov extesion theorem) by Yoneda Lemma and some limit theory in category theory. And the author left it as a exercise.
I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment there so I post a question here: Is what he said possible? If so, what category is he working in, what are the morphism? What is the actual proof? I've been trying to figure this out for several days but still have no any idea. Any reference or hint may be appreciated.

EDIT: I found a recent (2024) thesis on this topic here. In this paper the author discussed a categorical proof of Kolmogorov extension theorem using Kan extension. I'm not really familiar with these tools so I can't fully understand this paper and relavent proof.
I, now, have another question: why did the author didn't assume any extra properties on $\Omega$ but just assume it's a probability space in Section 5.3.4? Since the original version of Kolmogorov's requires $(\Omega_i)_{i\in I}$ to be $\mathbb{R}^n$ or satisfying some standard property.

I doubt that one can really substantiate Tom LaGatta's claim that Kolmogorov's theorem can be proved by Yoneda's lemma. Kolmogorov's theorem is about the existence of suitable limits (which probably can be described in categorical terms) and I don't think that Yoneda has much to say about this.

In general, I appreciate CT as a great explanation which also helps to set the scene for tools from homological algebra. Also for analysis and probability theory, this can be very helpful, and abstract things like the existence of the Stone-Cech compactification are very much enlightened by adjoint functor theorems. However, I don't think that concrete theorems like Kolmogorov's can be proved by just using CT.

@Jochen I hold the same doubt, but i'm not really sure. Since there are some examples that famous concrete theorems like Cayley's theorem can be proven by Yoneda, there may be a chance for Kolmogrov's. The point is that though I found a categorical version for Kolmogrov's theorem (see here), but still found no such proof :(

@Jochen Hey, I found a proof (not using Yoneda but Kan extension), see my edit. It would be great if you can answer my new question.

After having a very short look at Van Belle's thesis I am still not convinced. At least superficially, it seems that there are still very measure theoretic techniques necessary to obtain, e.g., Caratheodory's extension theorem (see, e.g., the proof of theorem 4.7.3 on page 101 as a random example). I don't feel competent to judge what kind of insights are added by CT
